How to pressurize a volume with gas (nitrogen) without a valve to connect to a tank, and to seal it without letting gas out
For reference, I'm currently a CAD engineering student going back to school after working as a designer for a year. I know common sense and how to make drawings, but I don't have much industry experience in water systems or engineering.
At work a customer has given us a example of a pulsation damper they would like us to make for them. While other people are working on similar smaller designs based on our current models, I'm supposed to figure out how they made it without a valve to charge or recharge it.
A simple drawing of the cross section we have:

From what I understand, this design, as well as the one we already use, is more popular in use with hydraulic fluid, but we and our customers use them in water systems to improve energy efficiency or reduce hydraulic shock.
Although there's plenty of documentation online about how pulsation dampers work and how to make them, I can't find any drawings or details on how models like this work. I found that certain Mercedes-Benz and Essex Industries have a similar model, but I can't find any actual details on the process of how a design like this would be pressurized from the top, then sealed to keep the specific gas and pressure in. Most designs are bolted together, sealed but with no pressure, or have a valve on the top for recharging like the model we currently manufacture.
So far my guesses, based on information used in other applications, are

The body is placed inside a purge chamber, the purge chamber is filled and pressurized, then it is welded inside of the chamber. Unless its a robot, this seems unlikely since the sample is mass produced and this sounds very time consuming.

Liquid form of the gas is poured inside the chamber, the chamber is sealed, then the gas is boiled. This seems unlikely for the prior reason, as well as that liquid nitrogen could maybe make the bladder brittle or damage it.


Do either of these guesses seem logical, or would there be a better, repeatable way of making something like this?

Depending on a highly elastic diaphragm, one way would be:

Pressurise the water-flow ports to drive the diaphragm to the top and drive out all the air.
Connect the nitrogen source to the fill port.
Connect the water-flow ports to vacuum and pull the diaphragm all the way down and, perhaps, into the vertical water port. The chamber will fill with nitrogen.
Remove the nitrogen source. You'll now have the chamber filled with nitrogen at atmospheric pressure.
Seal the top.
Release the vacuum.

